# Visually pleasing scatterplot of images?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'd like to make a scatterplot of images:

[image]

Here is my data you can use to try to answer my question:

```
pts = CloudGet[
 "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-e9c7e0a8-2832-4d10-9d87-2bdc3ad8ae5b/points"];
imgs=CloudGet[
 "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-e9c7e0a8-2832-4d10-9d87-2bdc3ad8ae5b/thumbnails"];
```

I have a set of 2D points (the pts variable above)

[image]

And each point is associated with a 70x70 pixel image (pts and imgs variable have the same order). I'd like to lay them out to look like the following (the exact positions need not be kept exactly the same during the layout processes). Each image should be snapped to a square grid, if I zoom in it looks like this:

[image]

**Second Attempt:**

```
g = Graphics[Inset @@@ Thread[{Magnify[#, 0.02] & /@ imgs, pts}], 
  ImageSize -> 700, AspectRatio -> 1/2, Background -> Black]
```

[image]

**Initial Attempt:**

So far this is all I have, but it is not squeezed together enough:

```
g = RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[200, 0.05]];  
v = Round[#, 0.1] & /@ (PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ 
     VertexList[g]);

(g = SetProperty[{g, #}, 
      VertexShape -> ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]]) & /@ 
  VertexList[g];
(g = SetProperty[{g, #}, VertexSize -> {"Scaled", .017}]) & /@ 
  VertexList[g];
Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> v]
```

[image]

Examples:

- https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/

Comment: Do you really want a graph, or did you just use that for plotting purpose? Looking at your first image I think you want to create a large blank raster then `ImageOverlay` each small image.

Comment: @Kuba, I;m trying to visualize clusters, so I just want to tweak them without destroying the clusters.

Comment: @george2079 You're right the graph is just for plotting purposes.

Comment: Added data as cloud objects!

Comment: `CloudGet` returns "StringForm::sfr: Item 1 requested in "The permutation vector `1` is incorrect. >>" out of range; 0 items available. >>"

Comment: @george2079 for both or just one?

Comment: both, could be because I only have a free access account.

Answer (score 2):

```
 i0 = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 70];
 Nest[(
   pos = RandomInteger[29, 2] 70;
   ImageCompose[#, i0, pos, {0, 0}]) &, 
 Image[ConstantArray[0, {30, 30} 70]], 200]
```

[image]